# Given a set of whole numbers $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, how many combinations of the set add to integer $N$?

Tags: combinatorial-number-theory

For a set of whole numbers from $1$ to $k$, how many combinations can be made that add to $N$?  I had half solved this problem not too long ago, and when plotted on a table I got a diagonal representation of the Pascal triangle. so I'm wondering if I did it correctly, and if so, why did Pascal's triangle appear? Numbers are allowed to repeat. So $1+1+1$ is a valid solution for $k=5$, $N=3$. Order does not matter, so $2+3$ and $3+2$ would be considered the same solution.

Comment: Here, $k$ is the maximum size of an integer which can appear in the sum? And repetitions are allowed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Did you really intend to include $0$? Along with "numbers are allowed to repeat", that seems to imply that there are always either no combinations or infinitely many combinations. Perhaps you only want to count sums of a certain size? Can you give some examples of what you think the number of combinations is for some values of $N$ and $k$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)